# How to jump to consecutive folders if conditions not matching

Tags: shell-script, directory

I have 4 directories, A,B,C,D in one path. If I am inside A, and some of my condition is not matching for it, say size is less than a limit, I need to continue with next folder, B and then to C,D etc without exiting. How?
I need the command to do the same

Comment: If this [almost identical question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396934/how-to-jump-to-consecutive-folders) is also yours please consider whether you need both, or if one can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in A B C D; do
    cd /path/to/"$dir"
    if ! test_condition ; then
        continue
    fi
    : do stuff in $dir
done
```

Comment: Let me clarify. My folder is an archive folder having A,B,C,D where folder "B" is having size limit of 500MB. So if it exceeds 500MB, i will delete files from B.Otherwise I should proceed to C and then to D and delete files from there, to maintain size limit of archive folder. Purging of files is another function which I am calling from here.

Comment: @Anony Clarifications to the question should be made _in_ the question by editing it, not in comments.